# Probe clientCaps with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to probe the [clientCaps](http://code.google.com/p/jstricks/source/browse/trunk/clientcaps.html?r=2) object in Javascript (I'm not very familiar with behaviours in MSIE). But not having much luck.

Due to other constraints, I can't really modify the HTML of the page and hence trying to add an element dynamically. The code I'm using is shown below - I keep getting exceptions (object doesn't support this property or method). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
                    var out="";
                    try {
                      var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                      var s = document.createElement("div");

                      // attempt 1 - exception
                      // s.id="oClientCaps";
                      // s.style.behaviour="url('#default#clientCaps')";
                      //
                      // attempt 2 - exception
                      // s.innerHTML='<a ID="oClientCaps" style="behavior:url(#default#clientcaps)"></a>';
                      //
                      // attempt 3 - exception
                      s.id="oClientCaps";
                      s.addBehavior ("#default#clientCaps");

                      b.appendChild(s);
                      var clids = Array('{7790769C-0471-11D2-AF11-00C04FA35D02}', // address bk
                          ...
                          '{08B0E5C0-4FCB-11CF-AAA5-00401C608500}'); // MS VM

                      for(i=0;i<clids.length;i++) {
                        if(oClientCaps.isComponentInstalled(clids[i],"ComponentID")){
                          out+=clsids[i] 
                             + oClientCaps.getComponentVersion(clids[i],"ComponentID") 
                             + '; ';
                        } else {
                          out+='N; '
                        }
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      out+="clientCaps failed";
                    }
                    return out;
```

TIA

Comment: Maybe it's this: `b.apendChild(s);`?

Comment: @Teemu: well spotted - but this was just a typo when I pasted the code - original was OK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the following works (although I'm not sure why the other methods failed):

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var s = document.createElement("div");
s.innerHTML="<div style='behavior:url(#default#clientCaps)' ID='oClientCaps' ></div>";
b.appendChild(s);
(etc)
```